Format faliure merging word template with *.csv file data
I get a format faliure pop up, when trying to merge a *.csv file datasource with a word template in a Cobol program. The faliure arises in following line of code:
MODIFY  someHandleNumber OpenDataSource(som file path including file name *.csv)
The regional settings in Windows corresponds fine with the data source (";" seperating values). What to do to prevent the pop up?
And please beare with me: english is not my first langauge and I know nothing about Microsoft Office and Windows setup.
Thanks in advance
Roar
I'm trying to merge a *.csv file datasource with a word template in a Cobol program. This should run automatecaly - and have done so - but I get a pop up asking for choice of sign for seperating values.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
